# How to resolve this strange table behavior?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to create a UI having tiles on my website **http://betaa.harshalgajjar.tk/ (100% Virus free)**
But, the first tile, as visible on the site acts strangely, even after having sufficient space for the text inside, it still squeezes the tiles below (the next `<tr>`) when mouse is over it.

For the table, I have used the following code:
`#tiles{table-layout:fixed;width:100%;height:80%;}`
However I wasn't able to fix the table layout, using `table-layout:fixed`, I also tried setting the max-height, but even that helped me nowhere.

I have provided some additional code for reference:

```
<table id="tiles" style="table-layout:fixed;max-height:80%;" cellspacing=20>
<tr><td style="background-color:#E18728;width:100px;height:100px;" class="tdtile"><div class="text">Harshal Gajjar<br><br> Programmer, music lover and tech enthusiast.hjka hjhajdh ajhd hahdqhw oiphjsadhuh uhw9uqh uhiusau wu hjhajdh ajhd hahdqhw oiphjsadhuh uhw9uqh uhiusau wu hjhajdh ajhd hahdqhwsau wu</div></td><td style="background-color:#5FCF80;width:100px;height:100px;"><div class="text">2</div></td><td style="background-color:#CD6A51;width:100px;height:100px;"><div class="text">3</div></td><td style="background-color:#C8FF92;width:100px;height:100px;"><div class="text">4</div></td></tr>
<tr><td style="background-color:#9351A6;width:100px;height:100px;"><div class="text">5</div></td><td style="background-color:#55ACEE;width:100px;height:100px;"><div class="text">6</div></td><td style="background-color:#C4302B;width:100px;height:100px;"><div class="text">7</div></td><td style="background:url('jobs.jpg');background-size:cover;width:100px;height:100px;"><div class="text">8</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

*where the `.text` is visible only on mouseover.

And the CSS:

```
#tiles{table-layout:fixed;width:100%;height:80%;}
#tiles tr td{text-align:left;color:rgba(255,255,255,1);-webkit-transition:0.5s all ease-in-out;vertical-align:top;font-size:1em;}
.text{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);height:35px;;position:relative;-webkit-transition:0.5s all ease-in-out;color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}
.text:first-line {color: #fff;font-size:1.5em;}
.text:hover{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);height:100%;position:relative;bottom:0px;color:rgba(255,255,255,1) !important;}
```

The screenshot for same issue:
Mouseout on first tile
[image]
Mouseover on first tile
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
.text{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);height:35px;;position:relative;-webkit-transition:0.5s all ease-in-out;color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}
```

to this

```
.text{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);height:20%;position:relative;-webkit-transition:0.5s all ease-in-out;color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}
```

simply changing `height:35px;` to `height:20%`  you can increase or decrease that 20% to change height.

Comment: Actually, I want two rows of equal height. Your suggestion, although solves the problem posted above, but creates a difference in heights. :) Can you pls provide an alternate method?